# Python: How to reference element inside a data structure [{

Tags: python, list, tuples

So i want to obtain the value in fingerprint below. Lets say this structure is called data.

Ive tries to get it with data[{'fingerprint'}]

```
[{
  "fingerprint": "93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e",
  "inactive_status": 0,
  "key_id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1.pca.u3yinjvmaqaavf7dswooxyoxygol8decj2wgj95anubobjxoipak00090146/ocid1.user.oc1.PCA.sr4ip9ckw9e5lnpbpog1o3dq2u9yqawnjkrvu5a60v534ncvp6wue36lrure/93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e",
  "key_value": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA73YAYlWJQvX6UQnV98ML\r\nUiVXZgI6Tqf+eTp9VUGrKiNzwvYXEtqHbNvcwi/gbnYvF8mgxwEvGbx/eEFdkNP4\r\nG4V4//Q5GRvGBpe8K7KxJ784xai6bW9Zrqs5reBbBr7fLRP330JVYlljfmBmTiaK\r\n5ydw5kImSjQDnPy/0dsD7w4gQ/zfjlYHtfkwDZSsPMvQJBOm5Zw4uXH1ozaPpNtP\r\nPhoZ6CEd+SQSmoQ7LnuxW1+wjHjyjXSyFni30yC6b5SYh5y7pxdPZZvlp/BEkj+f\r\nycjwlBUcV2PuEhChuSLJIRW403pIp0m8nDjAYsLDq/5G8kQ10exXpEMzJ2v6dScd\r\n7QIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
  "lifecycle_state": "ACTIVE",
  "time_created": "2020-10-08T08:35:11+00:00",
  "user_id": "ocid1.user.oc1.PCA.sr4ip9ckw9e5lnpbpog1o3dq2u9yqawnjkrvu5a60v534ncvp6wue36lrure"
}]
```

Comment: `lst[0]['fingerprint']`.....

Comment: `[` and `]` form a list, `{` and `}` a dictionary. So you must adress the dict within the list which boils down to (as @jizhihaoSAMA correctly said) `data[0]["fingerprint"]`.

Comment: Instead of giving `data[{'fingerprint'}]` try `data[0]['fingerprint']` The variable `data` is a list. You want to pick the first element (0th) which is a dictionary. Then pick the key `fingerprint`. That will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving

`data[{'fingerprint'}]`

try

`data[0]['fingerprint']`

The variable `data` is a list. You want to pick the first element (0th) which is a dictionary. Then pick the key fingerprint. That will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable:

```
data = [{
"fingerprint": "93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e",
"inactive_status": 0,
"key_id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1.pca.u3yinjvmaqaavf7dswooxyoxygol8decj2wgj95anubobjxoipak00090146/ocid1.user.oc1.PCA.sr4ip9ckw9e5lnpbpog1o3dq2u9yqawnjkrvu5a60v534ncvp6wue36lrure/93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e",
"key_value": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA73YAYlWJQvX6UQnV98ML\r\nUiVXZgI6Tqf+eTp9VUGrKiNzwvYXEtqHbNvcwi/gbnYvF8mgxwEvGbx/eEFdkNP4\r\nG4V4//Q5GRvGBpe8K7KxJ784xai6bW9Zrqs5reBbBr7fLRP330JVYlljfmBmTiaK\r\n5ydw5kImSjQDnPy/0dsD7w4gQ/zfjlYHtfkwDZSsPMvQJBOm5Zw4uXH1ozaPpNtP\r\nPhoZ6CEd+SQSmoQ7LnuxW1+wjHjyjXSyFni30yC6b5SYh5y7pxdPZZvlp/BEkj+f\r\nycjwlBUcV2PuEhChuSLJIRW403pIp0m8nDjAYsLDq/5G8kQ10exXpEMzJ2v6dScd\r\n7QIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
"lifecycle_state": "ACTIVE",
"time_created": "2020-10-08T08:35:11+00:00",
"user_id": "ocid1.user.oc1.PCA.sr4ip9ckw9e5lnpbpog1o3dq2u9yqawnjkrvu5a60v534ncvp6wue36lrure"
}]
```

Which means that you have a variable that has the data type [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp). This list contains
one element, which can be accessed by its index. Since it's the first element in the list, the index will be '0'.

The element on index [0] is a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).
A dictionary consist of {key : value} pairs, which means that you can access the *value* by referencing the *key*.

**Example of dictionary**

```
myDict = {"name":"myname"}  
print(myDict["name"])
```

This will print 'myName'.

If you combine this, you can access the *value* of 'fingerprint'

```
fingerprint = data[0]['fingerprint']
print(fingerprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution as proposed by jizhihao in form of expessions:

```
data = [{
  "fingerprint": "93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e",
  "inactive_status": 0,
  "key_id": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1.pca.u3yinjvmaqaavf7dswooxyoxygol8decj2wgj95anubobjxoipak00090146/ocid1.user.oc1.PCA.sr4ip9ckw9e5lnpbpog1o3dq2u9yqawnjkrvu5a60v534ncvp6wue36lrure/93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e",
  "key_value": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\nMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA73YAYlWJQvX6UQnV98ML\r\nUiVXZgI6Tqf+eTp9VUGrKiNzwvYXEtqHbNvcwi/gbnYvF8mgxwEvGbx/eEFdkNP4\r\nG4V4//Q5GRvGBpe8K7KxJ784xai6bW9Zrqs5reBbBr7fLRP330JVYlljfmBmTiaK\r\n5ydw5kImSjQDnPy/0dsD7w4gQ/zfjlYHtfkwDZSsPMvQJBOm5Zw4uXH1ozaPpNtP\r\nPhoZ6CEd+SQSmoQ7LnuxW1+wjHjyjXSyFni30yC6b5SYh5y7pxdPZZvlp/BEkj+f\r\nycjwlBUcV2PuEhChuSLJIRW403pIp0m8nDjAYsLDq/5G8kQ10exXpEMzJ2v6dScd\r\n7QIDAQAB\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
  "lifecycle_state": "ACTIVE",
  "time_created": "2020-10-08T08:35:11+00:00",
  "user_id": "ocid1.user.oc1.PCA.sr4ip9ckw9e5lnpbpog1o3dq2u9yqawnjkrvu5a60v534ncvp6wue36lrure"
}]

fingerprint = data[0]['fingerprint']

print(fingerprint)


'93:51:15:1b:72:f1:3c:f0:f5:51:7e:78:cf:21:d7:7e'
```